# path directory not working?

Tags: html, css

I've finished up my website and I'm trying to clean up the files. I've put all my images in a folder called images and I'm trying to set up the path directory from the root folder but to no avail. As far as I can tell I'm doing nothing wrong?

```
<img src="images/logo.png">
```

The root folder contains the html file with logo inside it and another folder called images with logo.png inside it.

Would anybody know what the problem is?

All help really appreciated!

Comment: try ./imaegs/logo.png

Comment: may be you used "images" as "Images"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue looks like relative paths, so instead of:

```
<img src="images/logo.png">
```

try

```
<img src="/images/logo.png">
```

In the suggested approach notice the leading forward slash `/`

You may find the following useful: http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Answer (score 2):

The path is right but if you are using a url rewrite like engine htaccess the paths may be problematic, then you can set an absolute path instead of a relative:

```
<img src="/images/logo.png">
```